# jQuery Perform action if checkbox "A" is the only one checked

Tags: jquery

Can you run a check to see if a checkbox is the only value checked against a group?

```
$("#ID").change(function() {
if ($("#checkboxA").is(":checked") && NOTHING ELSE IS CHECKED) {
 //do somethinge
} else {
//do something else
}
});
```

I need help with the "&& NOTHING ELSE IS CHECKED" and Im still not sure this would be a change function

Answer (score 4):

You could check that only one checkbox is checked and that checkbox has the id of the one you are looking for. **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yv8Ny/2/)**

```
$("#ID").change(function() {
    var checked = $("input:checkbox:checked");
    if (checked.length === 1 && checked[0].id === 'checkboxA') {
        //do something
    } 
    else {
        //do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you know 'checkboxA' will be the first element in the list?

Comment: Because if `checked.length` only has one value, the only value will be the first element. `&&` does short circuit evaluation in JavaScript

Comment: I usually go with .size() to check the result set, and forgot that .length works too. Thanks!

Comment: .size() just calls .length internally so I prefer to skip the extra function call and just check the property directly

Answer (score 1):

What about selecting all checked checkboxes with

```
$('input:checkbox:checked')
```

And then running a check to make sure the length of this list is equal to 1?